Is it possible to use an already working Barebones (328P) via FTDI to load a bootloader onto another 328P?
When testing / developing a proto type using a barebones board with 328P, I usually add a Serial to TTL adapter, which then allows me to modify and upload code as well as being able to the use Serial Monitor.
My question is, is it also possible to use the barebones via a Serial to TTL adapter to load a bootloader onto a blank 328P? I've tried once but it was unsuccessful. The setup was exactly the same as what I would normally do to load a bootloader onto blank chips using an UNO to barebones. The only difference was that I I replaced the UNO with an already working barebones and connected to the PC via FTDI.
I simply want to build a dedicated setup using ZIFF sockets to load a bootloader and code onto a blank 328P chips. If the answer is "yes" that's good enough for me to carry on again. I just don't want to waste valuable time when it is actually not possible at all. My ultimate is to get round to understanding all the options around  communications SPI etc etc.
All help will be greatly appreciated.

Yes, there is no reason why this should not work. With an 328p and a USB serial chip you already have much of what an Arduino Uno is. If you want more help, you should include more information about how exactly it didn't work for you.

Thanks, at this stage I don't understand the various comm protocols. So do I understand correctly that swopping from USB cable direct to the Arduino UNO will produce the same result as me using a barebones with a USB cable via  a Serial to TTL converter.... thanks again for helping. If above is true then previous effort may have failed because of some silly mistake I made. Again Thank You for helping. When I get it going I will share my experience.

The 328p on the Uno doesn't speak USB, so the Uno has its own USB Serial chip. If you use a 328p and a USB Serial board that is just the same.

Thanks, your input is so encouraging,  done some research on "Uno has its own USB Serial chip" and Arduino Docs revealed that UNO uses the atmega8U2 chip to achieve "USB to Serial" to communicate with the 328P. Also according to the same (Arduino DOCS) article,  "...some people  call the "USB to Serial"  a  "Serial to TTL" and that basically the FTDI module achieves the same result as the atmega8U2 does. So I shall rebuild the experiment and am expecting a positive result this time. Will build a single board, ZIFF sockets, to upload Bootloader and also capable of uploading sketches as well.

No, you can't upload  bootloader without bootloader via serial port. Bootloader is the "magic" that allows uploading the FLASH through the serial port. You have to upload the bootloader to the empty chip via the ISP.

My intention was to have the first Barebones already functioning complete with bootloader installed and communicating with the PC via Serial to TTL module. The second Barebones would have a Blank 328P plugged into a ZIFF socket which I would then load Bootloader onto via the first Barebones .... looks like i'm being sent back to the drawing board.

Yes, that is possible. The first board must contain the arduino ISP sketch. The second board must be connected via the RESET, MISO, MOSI, CLK signals. see  this

Thanks, have been doing a lot on the bread board without success.... going to have a good look at the link you provided.... then carry on with bread board. PS... I have been using an UNO successfully to load bootloaders for a while now, just for fun and learning curves decided to try and build a dedicated barebone station to do bootloader and also sketches. Thanks again

So after trying all of above and not (yet) winning , I have in the mean time, simply built a dedicated barebones with single ziff socket. Do load a  bootloader onto  blank 328P I have included and wired up a 6 pin female header to receive a removable cable that allows me to link up with the ISP pins on my UNO. Then also to upload a sketch and have Serial Monitor available, I've also wired up another 6 pin female header to receive the FTDI 232 Adapter. It all works very well....  this to just to preserve my UNO. PS ZIFF socket was just to big to replace the 328 on the UNO.  Thanks to all
